# How do I connect my sphero ollie to my Mac OSX?

Tags: ruby, macos, bluetooth, sphero, artoo

I'm trying to play with the ruby artoo gem. To do this, I need to first register the device with my bluetooth adapter on my Mac. I've opened the system bluetooth settings, my bluetooth is on, but scanning produces no results.

I'm unsure if I need to do something to my ollie first to turn it on and make it discoverable.

I've tried playing with the node `cylon-ble-scan` tools and poked around at some other projects, but nothing has worked so far.

Any clues?

Comment: From what I've found out, Sphero Ollie is not yet well supported under OSX like the original Sphero is. Time will tell if this changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find it on your typical scanner because your Ollie uses BLE, or Bluetooth Low Energy. Try finding a BLE scanner such as [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue/id639944780?mt=12), and you will be able to connect to it.